# Drools need org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper to run?

Tags: java, spring-boot, drools

I am using drools in my project. For some reason, drools is expecing the class `org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper`. This solves if I include `spring-jdbc` depencency, but I don't have any database configured so my app doesn't start.
Why does drools need `spring-jdbc`? Please help

UPDATE: I tried this with an older version of drools by using `drools-compiler` dependency (from [this](https://www.javainuse.com/drools_hello) tutorial). I got the same exception.

Below are my drools dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
    <artifactId>kie-ci</artifactId>
    <version>8.32.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
    <artifactId>drools-decisiontables</artifactId>
    <version>8.32.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

This is how I am setting it up:

```
public class DroolsBeanFactory {
    private KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();

    private void getKieRepository() {
        final KieRepository kieRepository = kieServices.getRepository();
        kieRepository.addKieModule(() -> kieRepository.getDefaultReleaseId());
    }

    public KieSession getKieSession(String droolsFilePath){
        getKieRepository();
        KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();

        kieFileSystem.write(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource(droolsFilePath));

        KieBuilder kb = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem);
        kb.buildAll();
        KieModule kieModule = kb.getKieModule();

        KieContainer kContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(kieModule.getReleaseId());

        return kContainer.newKieSession();
    }
}
```

Below is the exception I am getting

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'someService' defined in file [/Users/ps/workspace/forks/Project/target/classes/com/walmart/project/service/SomeService.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.walmart.project.service.SomeService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Rules compilation failed or interrupted
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1232) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at com.walmart.project.ProjectApplication.main(ProjectApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.walmart.project.service.SomeService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Rules compilation failed or interrupted
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:224) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1326) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Rules compilation failed or interrupted
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.processors.ImmutableRuleCompilationPhase.compileRulesLevel(ImmutableRuleCompilationPhase.java:285) ~[drools-compiler-8.34.0.Final.jar:8.34.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.processors.ImmutableRuleCompilationPhase.process(ImmutableRuleCompilationPhase.java:82) ~[drools-compiler-8.34.0.Final.jar:8.34.0.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.forEach(Arrays.java:4390) ~[na:na]
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.compileKnowledgePackages(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:456) ~[drools-compiler-8.34.0.Final.jar:8.34.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.buildRules(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:1015) ~[drools-compiler-8.34.0.Final.jar:8.34.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.doFirstBuildStep(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:989) ~[drools-compiler-8.34.0.Final.jar:8.34.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.build(CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:114) ~[drools-compiler-8.34.0.Final.jar:8.34.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.build(CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:104) ~[drools-compiler-8.34.0.Final.jar:8.34.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieProject.buildKnowledgePackages(AbstractKieProject.java:270) ~[drools-compiler-8.34.0.Final.jar:8.34.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieProject.buildKnowledgePackages(AbstractKieProject.java:216) ~[drools-compiler-8.34.0.Final.jar:8.34.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieProject.verify(AbstractKieProject.java:80) ~[drools-compiler-8.34.0.Final.jar:8.34.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildKieProject(KieBuilderImpl.java:282) ~[drools-compiler-8.34.0.Final.jar:8.34.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildAll(KieBuilderImpl.java:248) ~[drools-compiler-8.34.0.Final.jar:8.34.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildAll(KieBuilderImpl.java:195) ~[drools-compiler-8.34.0.Final.jar:8.34.0.Final]
    at com.walmart.project.config.DroolsBeanFactory.getKieSession(DroolsBeanFactory.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.walmart.project.service.SomeService.<init>(SomeService.java:59) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:211) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.get(ForkJoinTask.java:1006) ~[na:na]
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.processors.ImmutableRuleCompilationPhase.compileRulesLevel(ImmutableRuleCompilationPhase.java:283) ~[drools-compiler-8.34.0.Final.jar:8.34.0.Final]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:603) ~[na:na]
    ... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3166) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2309) ~[na:na]
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.TypeDeclarationUtils.processModifiedProps(TypeDeclarationUtils.java:302) ~[drools-compiler-8.34.0.Final.jar:8.34.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.TypeDeclarationCache.initTypeDeclaration(TypeDeclarationCache.java:158) ~[drools-compiler-8.34.0.Final.jar:8.34.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.TypeDeclarationCache.getAndRegisterTypeDeclaration(TypeDeclarationCache.java:93) ~[drools-compiler-8.34.0.Final.jar:8.34.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.TypeDeclarationBuilder.getAndRegisterTypeDeclaration(TypeDeclarationBuilder.java:69) ~[drools-compiler-8.34.0.Final.jar:8.34.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.TypeDeclarationManagerImpl.getAndRegisterTypeDeclaration(TypeDeclarationManagerImpl.java:53) ~[drools-compiler-8.34.0.Final.jar:8.34.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.getAndRegisterTypeDeclaration(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:676) ~[drools-compiler-8.34.0.Final.jar:8.34.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.PatternBuilder.processClassObjectType(PatternBuilder.java:309) ~[drools-compiler-8.34.0.Final.jar:8.34.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.PatternBuilder.build(PatternBuilder.java:173) ~[drools-compiler-8.34.0.Final.jar:8.34.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.PatternBuilder.build(PatternBuilder.java:142) ~[drools-compiler-8.34.0.Final.jar:8.34.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.PatternBuilder.build(PatternBuilder.java:124) ~[drools-compiler-8.34.0.Final.jar:8.34.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.GroupElementBuilder.build(GroupElementBuilder.java:66) ~[drools-compiler-8.34.0.Final.jar:8.34.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.RuleBuilder.build(RuleBuilder.java:98) ~[drools-compiler-8.34.0.Final.jar:8.34.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.processors.ImmutableRuleCompilationPhase.internalAddRule(ImmutableRuleCompilationPhase.java:339) ~[drools-compiler-8.34.0.Final.jar:8.34.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.processors.ImmutableRuleCompilationPhase.addRule(ImmutableRuleCompilationPhase.java:334) ~[drools-compiler-8.34.0.Final.jar:8.34.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.processors.ImmutableRuleCompilationPhase.lambda$compileRulesLevel$3(ImmutableRuleCompilationPhase.java:276) ~[drools-compiler-8.34.0.Final.jar:8.34.0.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachTask.compute(ForEachOps.java:290) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:746) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec$$$capture(ForkJoinTask.java:290) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doInvoke(ForkJoinTask.java:408) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.invoke(ForkJoinTask.java:736) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:159) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:173) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:233) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497) ~[na:na]
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.processors.ImmutableRuleCompilationPhase.lambda$compileRulesLevel$4(ImmutableRuleCompilationPhase.java:272) ~[drools-compiler-8.34.0.Final.jar:8.34.0.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1407) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec$$$capture(ForkJoinTask.java:290) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
    ... 40 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Because apparently internally it does use a database (like H2 or HSQLDB perhaps) or you configured drools somehow to use that.

Comment: @M.Deinum so is there any way to provide this class to Drools without using spring-jpa dependency? As this dependency is causing my application to crash as datasource is not configured

Comment: This question cannot be answered without, at minimum, sharing what dependencies specifically you're using from drools because I have never needed to import this particular library. You don't even share what version of drools we're discussing.

Comment: What makes you think you even need jpa? you need the spring-jdbc dependency and if that library depends on it I would expect it to be pulled in automatically (unless, as stated, you did something in your configuration to optionally enable something that requires it).

Comment: Drools doesn't internally use a database: it uses an in-memory rete tree (or similar; depends on what specific version we're talking about but it's in-memory.) There's something non-standard about how it's being set up, but we've nothing to go on here so nothing more can be said

Comment: I have added the drools dependencies, can you all please help me now?

Answer (score 0):

Understood the issue. In my DRL file, I was setting a global object that is a part of another library. When I opened the code of this object, it was annotated with `@Entity` and other JPA related annotations. This was causing ths issue.